move resource Ralation Manager into tab in filamentphp
how can I move the addressRelationManager into the tab at CustomerResorce create or edit page?
I have a Customer resource and an Address resource, customer can have many addresses, I want to show addresses into a tab blow the Customer edit or create page.
like attached image

